# Why does $\frac{dq}{dt}$ not depend on $q$? Why does the calculus of variations work?

Tags: differential-geometry, calculus-of-variations, implicit-differentiation

The Euler–Lagrange equations for a bob attached to a spring are
$${d\over dt}\left({\partial L\over\partial v}\right)=\left({\partial L\over\partial x}\right)$$

*But is $v$ a function of $x$? Normal thinking says that $x$ is a function of $t$ and $v$ is a function of $t$, but it is not necessary that $v$ be a function of $x$. Mathematically, however, $x=f(t)$ and $v=g(t)$, so $g^{-1}(v)=t$ and $x=f(g^{-1}(v))$.*

The chain rule should be applied in these equations – why not here? I had previously asked this question on the physics Stack Exchange but it was marked a duplicate. In [one of the answers there](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/885/why-does-calculus-of-variations-work/2908#2908) I found that the dedication of William Burke's *Applied Differential Geometry* read

> *To all those who, like me, have wondered how you can change $\dot q$ without changing $q$.*

I couldn't understand the answer there. My mathematics is not that good. So I asked it here again. If someone could give an answer without the concept of manifolds, I think I will be able to understand it.

***And Most importantly answers here say that notation is not that, but W. Burke has another reasons while the answers in the link have another reason. So what is the correct reason ? Like in f=(g(t)) we apply the chain rule. So why not here  when f'(x) is function of f(x)?***

Answer: It's so because the q and q dot are explicit functions of time so their partial derivative with each other is 0.....

Comment: It would be helpful if you gave us a link to the physics SE answer you're talking about

Comment: @Omnomnomnom  Yes off course just a second

Comment: First of all even if you have a function $g$ defined by $g(t)=v$ you have no guarantee that a function $g^{-1}$ satisfying $g^{-1}(g(t))=t$ even exists.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom  I have edited the answer to contain the link to the same question in Physics Stack Exchange

Comment: @ParclyTaxel you edited out [this link](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/885/why-does-calculus-of-variations-work)

Comment: @ryanp16  But for some function it would pe possible. I mean to say if there is no guarantee then anything can be possible

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Has been added back.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/580858/11127

Comment: @Qmechanic  I found this after passing through your link in your answer to this question http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/885/why-does-calculus-of-variations     ..."The point is that since the equation of motion is of 2nd order, one is still entitled to make 2 independent choices of initial conditions: 1 initial position and 1 initial velocity.)  I read through your answer and it was very helpful. If you could please explain the above point more considering I am a beginner in Lagrangian , I would get the point. Because this Point looks to be the basic thinG.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is $\frac{\operatorname dy'}{\operatorname dy}$ zero, since $y'$ depends on $y$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/580858/why-is-frac-operatorname-dy-operatorname-dy-zero-since-y-depends-on)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I find that calculus of variations could benefit pedagogically from a few more "dummy-variables".

Here's how I think about it: $L$, properly speaking, is a function on three parameters. That is, $L:\Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R$ so that $L(u_1,u_2,u_3)$ is a number for any three inputs $u_1,u_2,u_3$.

We're interested in the function $L(t,x(t),x'(t))$.  The Euler Lagrange equations should then be written as 
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial L}{\partial u_3}(t,x(t),x'(t)) = \frac{\partial L}{\partial u_2}(t,x(t),x'(t))
$$
and this is what the Euler-Lagrange equation is *really* talking about.

Certainly, if we wanted to compute $\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}(t,x(t),x'(t))$ with the usual definitions (or, I guess, with the "alternate interpretation"), we'd have some kind of chain rule to work through.  That is, we'd have
$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}(t,x(t),x'(t)) = \frac{\partial L}{\partial u_2} \frac{\partial u_2}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial L}{\partial u_3} \frac{\partial u_3}{\partial x} = 
\frac{\partial L}{\partial u_2}(t,x,x') + \frac{\partial L}{\partial u_3}(t,x,x') \frac{\partial x'}{\partial x}(t)
$$
However, this second interpretation is **not** the evaluation we're interested in.

Comment: So is it correct to say that in a sense dq/dt is a dependent on (function of)  q or is it wrong ?

Comment: It is indeed correct to say that $dq/dt$ is dependent on $q$.  However, we still evaluate $\partial{L}/\partial{q'}$ as if there is no such dependence.

Comment: But why do we do that and not apply the chain rule as if there is no such dependence when the truth is that dq/dt is dependent on q. Is n't it necessary to apply chain rule where the variable being differentiated depends on another variable ? I mean to say that we have been applying this concept of using chain rule throughout single and multivariate and even vector calculus . Why are we not applying it here ? Wouldn't the final result go wrong if we know that dq/dt depends on q and we still not apply the chain rule ?

Comment: Again, the real point here is that the formula is written with bad notation. They **mean** the first thing, even though they write it like the second thing

Comment: Ok , I think I have started getting it.  Is it that by the correct Euler Lagrange equations we will get what we are looking for. And by the application of the chain rule we will get something which isn't important and ni where connected to the principle of least action. We should be using the correct symbols and correct notation. We mean the 1st thing and write it like the 2nd thing . I have got it right ?

Comment: That all sounds right, yes. The reason we write it the second way is that people prefer to call $u_1,u_2,u_3$ $t,x,x'$. If you don't give separate names to the arguments of $L$, those two formulas end up looking the same.

Comment: Ok Thanks a lot , I think I am getting it now . Just one thing more. Why do they (physicists) prefer to call it by that way when their this way leads to a big confusion. Is it just big long historical convention or have they a subtle reason to call it so ?

Comment: And one thing more. I didn't understand Andrew D Hwang's answer much but is it contradicting yours ?

Comment: I think it's because of the historical convention, as you say. A physicist would probably say that the $u$'s are just unnecessary labels. Andrew's answer does not contradict mine.

Comment: Ok Thanks , I got it finally !

Comment: I had this http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/257947/work-done-according-to-newtons-principia    question on Physics stack exchange. I got an answer there. But I didn't get it wholly. I put it here on maths but it didn't gather much attention. After quite of lot efforts , I haven't been able to find the fault in my argument in the question. Neither were the professors in my university able to find a fault. Yet , I feel that one of the answers given there could be a right one , though I didn't get it completely.

Comment: Since I got this answer of yours , I thought of asking you directly (considering the prolonged problem it was causing and I wanted to find the fault . The fault probably lies somewhere in taking infinitesimals. ) I would be very grateful if you could answer it in detail. Thanks in advance !

Comment: Sorry to be abrupt but I think if I am getting what you mean, I think it's probably not right. The correct thing is that the partial derivative of v w. r. t to x and vice versa are 0...The corresponding total derivatives are not 0 but partial ones are 0...and that I thing is a one line answer

Comment: I have no idea what you’re trying to say other than that you think my answer is wrong

Comment: write out a simple lagrangian T-V.. In the potential term (which is just a function  of x not x dot (v) what I have essentially written in question means that while taking the partial derivative of the lagrangian with respect to x dot (v) a term should also come from the potential term since x depend on v ( or vice versa) but in actuality it doesn't... Why.. Because you can write down the partial derivative of x with x dot and see it is 0...This is the answer the partial derivative is 0 .... I hope you can see why.. I hope you can get me now... If not please let me know

Comment: It depends how you define the “partial derivative of x with v”. I iron out that definition in my answer. There is a valid definition of “partial derivatives” for which the derivative of x with respect to v is potentially non-zero

Comment: I don't understand how that definition works atleast intuitively... Why have you taken the derivatives with u2.. etc.. Both the L that you write are functions of x x dot and t... I can just see that those partial derivatives will be 0...I can't understand how they will be non 0 in your example... If you wish you might explain in more detail what exactly you are saying..

Comment: In my definition, $L$ is a function with 3 inputs. The inputs that we happen to plug in are $t,x,v.$ An example where the derivative is not zero: if $x=t^{-1}$, then $v=-x^2$ and (in some sense) the derivative of $v$ with respect to $x$ is $-2x$.

Comment: ohkk i got what you are saying.... It's a matter of definition....

Answer (score 1):

Boiled down, the issue appears to be:

- For a *particular function* $f$, "the velocity is determined by the position": Precisely, if you know $f$, then (in practice) the value of $x = f(t)$ (essentially) determines the value of $v = f'(t)$ (as mentioned in your question, up to the relatively minor ambiguity noted in ryan16's comment).
- The Lagrangian, however, is defined on the *space of functions*, and knowledge of the *height* of a graph $x$ at one point tells you nothing about the *slope* $v$ at that point. (To deduce $f'(t)$ from $f$, you must know the values of $f$ in some open interval about $t$. The only relationships between the values $f(t)$ and $f'(t)$ are global, coming from boundary conditions and the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.)

---

In case it's helpful, think of a three-dimensional Cartesian space with coordinates $(t, x, v)$. Given a function $f$, compare the two paths:
$$
\gamma_{1}(t) = \bigl(t, f(t), 0\bigr),\qquad
\gamma_{2}(t) = \bigl(t, f(t), f'(t)\bigr).
$$
Convince yourself that a "small perturbation" of $f$ (introducing a zag of small height, say) can have a dramatic effect on $\gamma_{2}$ yet no visible effect on $\gamma_{1}$.

Comment: Thanks . I got it from your Omnomnomnom answers and after thinking on the difference in the 2 paths of the last lines of your answer

Answer (score 1):

I wrote on [another post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1872735/restating-euler-lagrange-equation-with-alternative-notation) about this matter. The way people write Euler-Lagrange equation is pretty confusing to me, so I decided to abandon the use of the notion "differentiate with respect to a variable" to clear things up. Hopefully you can follow the following notations.

Let $x:[t_1,t_2]\to \Bbb R$ be a smooth enough function. For this function, define another function $f_x:[t_1,t_2]\to \Bbb R^3$ by $$f_x(t):=(t,x(t),x'(t)).$$ Let $L:\Bbb R^3\to \Bbb R$ be the Lagrangian that is a smooth enough function. The functional to be optimised is usually written as $$S[x]=\int_{t_1}^{t_2}L(t,x(t),x'(t))dt.$$ But in our notations, we write it as $$S[x]=\int_{t_1}^{t_2}L\circ f_x$$ and we no longer need to specify that we integrate with respect to $t$ because the domain of $L\circ f_x$ is just an interval.

Partial derivatives of $L$ give rise to new functions. In our case, we concern about $$\partial_{e_2}L:\Bbb R^3\to \Bbb R$$ and $$\partial_{e_3}L:\Bbb R^3\to \Bbb R$$ where $e_2, e_3$ are vectors in the standard basis for $\Bbb R^3$.

In our notations, the Euler-Lagrange equation would be stated as $$(\partial_{e_3}L\circ f_x)'(t)-(\partial_{e_2}L\circ f_x)(t)=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

Many beginners go through this pain, and it all is the fault of physicists who use the extremely confusing notation $\dot q$. The correct approach is to understand that the Lagrangian (assuming that it does not depend explicitly on time) is defined on the *tangent space*, and in a local trivialization the points of the tangent space have coordinates $(x_1, \dots, x_n, v_1, \dots, v_n)$, where $(x_1, \dots, x_n)$ are coordinates on the base of the fibration ("the configuration space", as physicists call it), and $(v_1, \dots, v_n)$ are coordinates in the standard fiber. Therefore, $x$ and $v$ are independent coordinates.

Comment: Was back at this question. I still can't get that v is a function of x or q dot of q . Even if Lagrangian is on the tangent space  , it can't change the fact that q dot is a function of q . So q dot being a function of q whether in tangent space or not we must apply chain rule !!